# Select values from table, IDs are in one column

Tags: mysql

I have this MySQL query which works great, I only need to grab `advantages.value` for every id in `properties.advantages.` As you can see in the image, column Advantages is wierdly set (at least for me, I didn't create this) and IDs are separated by `-`. How can I get those values?

```
SELECT 
properties.id,
(SELECT types.value FROM types WHERE types.id = properties.type_id) as types,
properties.price,
properties.town_id,

**( SELECT advantages......),**

towns.id, 
towns.value 
FROM properties
LEFT JOIN towns
ON properties.town_id=towns.id 
WHERE properties.published='1'
```

[image][image]

Comment: What's the question ?

Comment: Hm sorry, I need to get those values, for every ID in column

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is the line with you're having trouble with?

```
**( SELECT advantages......),**
```

You can use `LIKE` with `CONCAT()` to compare them :

```
SELECT a.advantagesCol FROM advantages a
WHERE CONCAT('-',properties.id,'-') LIKE a.Id_Column
```

Comment: I can't get any value, the result is always NULL. If a column 'properties .advantages' has '-1-' then the selected value from table 'advantages.value'  should be "Great". If a columns has '-1-2-3-', the selected value should be something like "Great, Splendid, Bad". Is there a foreach or something similar in MySQL I could use in nested SELECT statement?